# Upgrading to 20.04 from 18.04 froze my laptop, can I reboot without damaging my pc/its files?

Tags: boot, upgrade, 20.04, reboot

I decided to finally upgrade to 20.04 with the software updater, and I got almost the entire way but it froze at
`Removing obsolete conffile /etc/default/speech-dispatcher ...` 
Can I reboot without harming anything? Would it be smarter to wait? Would it be a good idea to try the upgrade again after I reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it broke everything, had to press escape on startup and then boot into recovery mode, I was able to finish installing 20.04 packages from there. I kinda hate 20.04 so I am downgrading now